# Update tkinter canvas when button is clicked

Tags: python, button, lambda, tkinter

I want to update the name of the child when you press one of the buttons below. With this lambda function, I always get the last name no matter which button is pressed. Is it possible to fix it using lambda functions? As far as I have seen lambda functions work well with define values but I have not seen any examples with variables. How can I fix it? Thanks,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#------------------------------------------------------------

__title__= 'Control'
__date__ = '10/07/2017'
__version__ = '0.0.1'

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Panel():
    def __init__(self, database, name):

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root. title('Control V' + __version__)
        self.root.configure(bg='beige')

        self.window = ttk.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=2, relief="raised",
                                padding=(10,10))
        self.window.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.window.option_add("*Font", "Helvetica 12")

        # Row 0
        self.header = ttk.Label(self.window, text=name, padding=(1,1), 
                                anchor='center')
        self.header.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

        # Row 1

        for col, record in enumerate(database, 0):
            name = database[col]['Letter']
                label = ttk.Button(self.window, text=name,
                        command=lambda *args: self.get_name(col, database))
                label.grid(row=1, column=(col), sticky='ew') 

        # All set
        self.root.mainloop()        


    def get_name(self, row, database):
        name = database[row]['Name']
        self.header.configure(text=name)

def main():

    database = [
        {'Letter': 'A', 'Name': 'Zara'},
        {'Letter': 'B', 'Name': 'Ezra'},
        {'Letter': 'C', 'Name': 'Amy'},
    ]
    name = database[0]['Name']
    my_panel = Panel(database, name)
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change get_name to a curried function:

```
def get_name(row, database):
    name = database[row]['Name']
    def _get_name():
        self.header.configure(text=name)
    return _get_name
```

and replace the command declaration with this returned function:

```
 label = ttk.Button(self.window, text=name,
                    command=self.get_name(col, database))
```

the result is as expected.

(What this does is define the return value of the button click when you create the button, rather than trying to pass in a parameter later. Your original code had all the buttons depend on 'col' (the variable). This remains the last thing it was set to (2->Amy), which explains why you were always getting that result.)

Comment: Kadnarim, thank you. I have never used before curried functions. It worked fine, as you told me. I only had to add self in your get_name definition.Thanks !!